# Instant search after starting a search in the top right corner box

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, search

In the top right corner of the page there is a text box for search that is expands after search is started.

As you search for a question after you begin a question there is an instant search operation on the results.

Is it possible to show instant result on top right text box?

It would make that box more useful.